# Bash 4.4+ returns error if "break" is called within function

Tags: bash

For Bash < 4.4 this works fine

```
function() {
    if [something happens]; then break ; fi
}

while [ ... ]
do
   function
done
```

Basically, bash < 4.4 exits this while loop when "something happens", whereas bash 4.4+ returns error "break: only meaningful in a `for',`while', or `until' loop" and does not exit the while loop.

How can I fix this to work for all bash versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is called from the while loop, but the break statement can't see the while loop from where it is. You have two options:

1. Instead of having a while loop call the function, have the function be in-line, and have all the logic contained within the while loop.
2. Change the function so that there is a 0/1 return value, and have an if statement to determine if the loop should exit, i.e.:

.

```
function() {
    if [something happens]; then return 0; else return 1; fi
}

while [ ... ]
do
   if function; then break; fi
done
```

Comment: I think you want `if function; then break; fi`

Comment: I did not remember that was how bash worked. Thank you for the tip. Fixed =)

Answer (score -2):

You can also use `eval`, it works as if you sourced a single function:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env bash
>
> i=0
>
> a() {
>     echo 'if [ "$i" -eq 3 ] ; then break ; fi'
> }
>
> while [ ... ]
> do
>    i=$((i+1))
>    eval "$(a)"
> done
>
> printf -- "exited\n"
> ```

I tested this on `bash 4.4.23` built from `git` and `bash 4.3.46`.

*EDIT*:

As correctly noted in the comment below, this method is fragile and should be used with caution. All in all, I like [jeremysprofile's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5889131/jeremysprofile) answer more.

Comment: This is error prone and bad practice, and may end up being exploitable.

Comment: Agree, I will emphasize it in my answer.

Comment: I did leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks, but downvote was given after your comment was posted so I wasn't sure if it was you who downvoted the answer. I don't think this answer deserves a downvote, it's absolutely correct though.

Comment: Rather than being used with caution, this should not be used *at all*. It provides no benefit over safer alternatives.

Comment: I don't agree. It's always good to show all possibilities offered by a language and explained why some are preferred over others.

Comment: I agree that it's good to offer multiple solutions with different tradeoffs. Unrelated answers using `eval` may contribute multiple point of views by saying "this is fragile but the only way to stay POSIX compliant" or "this is fragile but significantly easier for a once-off script on known data" or "you may have seen this in the Advanced Bash Scripting guide, but don't be tempted because ...". This answer doesn't do that. It's obviously nothing against you, it's just that users looking at the score will now immediately know not to use it without having to read through the edits and comments.